# vba error running a UPDATE command

Tags: ms-access, vba

Getting the error data type conversion error running this code.
the data is from text boxes set to data type rich text.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblISPServices", "SET Location=& Me.cboLocation,ServiceType =  & Me.cboSType, BBProvider = & Me.txtBBProvider" & "WHERE ID= & Me.txtID.Tag"
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

Remember to get variable or control values from the VBA code and rest should be string inside double quotes.

When generating such SQL statement to execute remember 3 rules

1) String data type fields should have single quote for string value so I had put single quote before & after location for e.g. '" & Me.cboLocation & "'
2) Number data type do not need single quote, so remove single quote for ID field for e.g. ID= " & Me.txtID.Tag
3) Date data type will have # instead of single quote for e.g. #" & Now() & "#

My assumption is , in the table tblISPServices field Location is Text Data type, ServiceType is Text data type, DBProvider is Text data type and ID is Numeric.

Observe how I made changes to get variable(control property) from VBA to generate String variable.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblISPServices SET Location= '" &   Me.cboLocation & "', ServiceType =  '" & Me.cboSType & "', BBProvider = '" & Me.txtBBProvider  & "' WHERE ID= " & Me.txtID.Tag
```

Note : remember while generating such string make sure you do not join any keyword to string or number for e.g. following is wrong SQL since it does not separate where

```
BBProvider = '" & Me.txtBBProvider  & "'WHERE ID= " & Me.txtID.Tag
```

Correct SQL would be,

```
BBProvider = '" & Me.txtBBProvider  & "' WHERE ID= " & Me.txtID.Tag
```